# Two function calls on input field, one onBlur and one not in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angular-ngmodel, angular-ui-typeahead

I have a typeahead field with two functions to trigger. One should be on-blur, this is the validation of the field. The other should be as the user types, this is the function `uib-typeahead`uses.

Right now I'm using `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"` but then it won't trigger the typeahead as the user types.

Is there a way to make the validation function trigger onBlur and the typeahead trigger normally?

For example, I call a directive number-validation that I want to call on blur. Then in the typeahead I want to call triggerfunction as a user types.

```
                          <input
                           number-validation
                           type="text"
                           maxlength="10"
                           class="form-control input-sm"
                           ng-model="number"
                           ng-change="number.elsewhere = null"
                           required
                    uib-typeahead="number for number in triggerfunction($viewValue)"
                    typeahead-template-url="/template.html"
                    typeahead-loading="Loadinglocations" typeahead-on-select="SelectFunction($item, 1)" typeahead-wait-ms="3"
                    typeahead-min-length="3">
```

Answer (score 1):

For "blur", you can use "ng-blur". For the type-ahead feature, use "ng-keyup".

Here is a fiddle with an example...

https://jsfiddle.net/eh2morxb/

And, here's the code...

```
<input type="text" ng-model="inputText" ng-blur="blurHandler()" ng-keyup="typeAhead()" placeholder="Type something...">

angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.inputText = "";
  $scope.typeAheadMessage = "";
  $scope.blurMessage = "";

  $scope.blurHandler = function() {
    $scope.blurMessage = "Perform input validation on " + $scope.inputText;
  };

  $scope.typeAhead = function() {
    $scope.typeAheadMessage = "Perform type-ahead lookup on " + $scope.inputText;
  };
}])
```

Comment: would this handle calling a directive? I've updated my question to provide an example.

Comment: That depends on the directive. You don't actually call directives, they act according to how they are designed. In the case of a custom validation directive, you would want to bind it to the $parsers collection. Angular takes care of the rest.

Comment: I already have a working custom validation, and I want it to trigger onBlur. This works using ng-model-options but apparently not with ng-blur. Binding it to $parsers won't help because $parsers are called any time a user changes the value.

Comment: If you have the blur functionality working using ng-model-options, I would assume you could simply stick with that method and add ng-keyup for type-ahead. Is it possible to create a fiddle that includes your custom validation?

Comment: That method would make sense, except the typeahead is already using uib-typeahead. I don't know how to also incorporate the ng-keyup on top of that. The custom validation just checks if the number is valid, if not it opens a new window.

Comment: Ok. I see in your new example now that you're using UI Bootstrap. That definitely changes things. There is no use for ng-keyup if you are already using uib-typeahead. Now, I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish. Are you simply trying to limit the input to numbers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112076/discussion-between-jenryb-and-wondergrub).

Answer (score 0):

you can utilize the   `ng-blur`directive to trigger an event on blur https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur

Comment: I know how to trigger something on blur. I don't want to trigger BOTH functions on blur, only one. I've added an example to demonstrate/